# Limits of SQLite 

Tags: sqlite

How far can one take the sqlite database from a single-user , embedded , prototype oriented db engine ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/784173/27310 to get an idea of how big SQLite databases can get in theory without performance problems. However, I'd suggest that you use a good [database abstraction layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) so you don't have to worry about the underlying database at all. That way, once you hit SQLite's working limits, you can switch over to a non-embedded RDBMS without much work.